# Set dynamic clientID to retrive value with javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to set a custom `ClientID` to my `DropDownList` to later on be able to get the selected value using javascript.

Setting it like
`ClientID="<%=MyVar%>"` it works fine, but when I try to concatenate some string then it messes up.

`ClientID="dropdown_<%=MyVar%>"` the output would be
literally clientid="dropdown_<%=MyVar%>"

It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a public method on your web page that concatenate the string then you can call it from the page source (easier to maintain and reuse)

```
public string GetClientId()
{
  return "dropdown" + yourVar;
}

ClientID="<%=GetClientId()%>"
```

Comment: Would it be efficient to create public method for just a control name?

Comment: this is just a tip but it would be something similar that can be reused

Comment: Did the trick. I used a similar function to control the diferent id's I need to check. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Note that I have moved the concatenation inside the server-side code, and used single quotes on the client side, to allow the double-quotes server-side.

```
ClientID='<%="dropdown_" + MyVar%>'
```

Comment: Stills outputs <%="dropdown_" + MyVar%> literally as id